Bash scripts do not function correctly in Ubuntu 24.04
When I run my Bash scripts (launchpad.net/linuxha) and (launchpad.net/linuxsoho) in Ubuntu 24.04, I receive the following errors:
./LinuxHA.sh: 175: read: Illegal option -s
./LinuxHA.sh: 355: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")

./LinuxSOHO.sh: 65: read: Illegal option -s
./LinuxSOHO.sh: 94: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")

These two scripts work just fine in Ubuntu 22.04, so something changed in Bash with the new Ubuntu 24.04 operating system.

Can you also show the corresponding part of the script?

Looks to me from the error that you're using sh to run a script that requires bash. They're two different shells; bash syntax is only guaranteed to work when you're using bash to run the script.

(and read -s is likewise a feature that sh isn't guaranteed to offer)

That said, we don't follow links here (and also don't consider screenshots) for purposes of determining whether a question follows our rules. You need to have a [MRE] in the text of the question itself for that question to be on topic
